# How do I make the colors match between two different monitors?

Tags: windows-7, display, multiple-monitors, color-profiles

I have two monitors. Windows on one screen appear with a yellow background (instead of transparent/white).

When I move a window between the monitors it changes its background color.

Any idea how do I remove the yellow background?

I have tried all suggestions with color management - did not solve my problem.

I run Windows 7 Ultimate

Two monitors:

- Samsung SyncMaster 226bw
- MAG ck2255af

[image: Attached a pic of my 2 monitors with 2 different background on the same window]

This is not a duplicate question since it has nothing to do with Monitor Calibration Software.

The solution (by AFH) is adjusting the monitor itself by changing to warm temperature.

Comment: You need to change the colour settings on the monitor itself: try raising the colour temperature first, then, if you can't get a satisfactory balance, adjust the individual colours.

Comment: It is not a duplicated question, by using the calibration software, you would achieve what you want so I respectfully disagree its not a duplicate

Comment: Calibration software is a possible solution, but an expensive and likely unnecessary one if you are not doing professional graphic art or video work. Adjusting the color settings on each monitor, as noted before, will work for 90% of cases like this and should generally have acceptable results.

Comment: I agree with @Ramhound that Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007's reference is related to, but not the same as this question. If the question is reopened, I'll submit an answer for the benefit of others.

Comment: @AFH you do realize I think it's a duplicate right?

Comment: @Ramhound - No, I don't realise that. Your comment implies that you _don't_ think it's a duplicate: how else does one understand "It is not a duplicated question"?

Comment: @AFH - I forgot the quotes (or simply phrased my statement oddly), but the last part of my sentence is clear though, "I respectfully disagree its not a duplicate " - I was attempting to address the believe, It was a duplicate, I was using the entire statement as a noun.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't said how your monitors are connected, but, unless you deliberately set different colour profiles on the two interfaces (which you can verify by swapping the connectors) the difference is going to be the colour settings on the monitor itself.

First, try raising the colour temperature; then, if you can't get a satisfactory balance, adjust the individual colours.

An alternative approach is to look at the settings on the other monitor and duplicate them, before making adjustments from there if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

This is always a very difficult challenge when using two different monitors. It's always best to use the same make/model monitor and the same connection type (e.g. VGA, DVI, HDMI, DisplayPort) if you want to make sure the colors match.

Aside from the already mentioned adjusting of the individual monitor color temperature and RGB levels... I strongly suspect the left monitor is connected using a VGA cable and the one on the right is connected with DVI (please confirm). This would further exacerbate the difference when you mix analog with digital.

If you reset the left monitor to defaults and it still has the yellow discoloration, then it would lead me to believe you either have a bad cable, the connection is loose, or the monitor itself is bad. I've seen many times when a VGA cable is bent beyond it's bend radius too many times you will see a tint of a particular color (I've personally seen blue, yellow, and red).

(Qualification: IT Coordinator who has setup over 100 dual monitor setups for work).